# Matlab: Export concatenation of cell arrays into a txt file

Tags: arrays, matlab, text, export, cell-array

I have two different sets of arrays within an array, which I called:

```
y={...}; % cell array of 1x1, with a 26x1 cell array within it.
Only_Data={...} %cell array of 525x1, with 525 different 1x12 cell arrays
```

**The data that's within the arrays is string**. I want to concatenate these two arrays into one and print that final result into a .txt file. But I'm having problems doing the last part.

This is what I've done for that purpuse:

```
new_subject3=[y; Only_Data];
new_subject3;
outfile='mynewfile';
filename=[outfile,'.txt'];

fid=fopen(filename,'w');

[nrows,ncols] = size(new_subject3);
for row = 1:nrows
    fprintf(fid ,'%s\n', new_subject3{row}{1:end});
end
fclose(fid);
```

For some reason I'm not aware of, it only prints the '**y**' array, but doesn't print anything from the '**Only_Data**' array. Why would that be? I'm clueless. I'm sure it's not about the type of data, but further than that I don't know.

I'll be glad to learn how to do this, thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your code with a smaller dataset and it turns out to execute correctly. I think something you can do is first to make sure nrows is of expected value, and cells in Only_Data are non-empty. You can also manually execute each fprintf, one after another, to command window to debug.

Comment: @MingjingZhang thanks to debugging I knew 'Only_Data' was the one making problems. 

This is 'y': http://imgur.com/a/hyynj
This is Only_Data: http://imgur.com/a/BgUhs

My guess is that could be the way I'm going through the Only_Data part of the array, maybe using another loop within the loop, but I don't know, I've tried different things and they have not worked out. 

If you think of something, don't doubt to tell me. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Your method seems fine as is. Sometimes the data may be printed correctly, but for some reasons we cannot see them. Try reducing y{1} to a 2x1 cell array, and Only_Data to 3 x 1, then see if you can still reproduce the error. If the error disappears, then gradually add removed data back to locate the problem; if the error persists, then please paste a code snippet that can generate y and Only_Data so that other people can reproduce the problem too.

Comment: @MingjingZhang I think I found the problem, it's in the size of the second array. 

The information from 'Only_Data' comes from an array I called 'C' that are 525 elements of 1x1 size. I used textscan so I can modify some of the data.

Textscan can transform that array into an array of different size. It changed the pieces from 1x1 to 1x12. If I can reverse that, I'll solve my problem. 

I know, because I tried printing 'C' and did without problems. 

Do you know a way to reverse the effect of 'textscan'?

Comment: @MingjingZhang I managed to print, but I lost the initial format. 

The issue was the type of data, I used char or cell2mat on the second array that's within Only_Data.